# Stretch background image in swift programatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, background

How do I stretch the background image in swift programatically. This is my current code

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "back.png")!)
```

I know how to strech if it was just UIImageView, but not sure about self.view

Answer (score 3):

**Xcode 8.0** | **SWift 3.0**

```
    let img: UIImage = UIImage(named: "YOURIMAGENAME")!
    self.view.layer.contents = img.cgImage
```

Hope it will help everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with `UIEdgeInsets`

```
var backImage = UIImage(named: "1234")

var resizablebackImage = backImage?.resizableImageWithCapInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top:10,left:0,bottom:10,right:0))

self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage:resizablebackImage!)
```

Comment: @djay, it should be, if image size smaller than your container then that defiantly will be work.